# Solr index rebuild on CD servers

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing

I am working on a client applciation on sitecore 8.1

we have one CM and multiple CD server , The CM solr instance and CD solr instance are pointing to 2 seperate instances , configured as master and master (incorrectly)

- CM- https://solr00.com:8983/solr
- CD- https://solr01.com:8983/sol

Indexing Strategy = OnPublishEndAsync

https://solr01.com:8983/solr indexes are not updated on publish of an item , is there a way to ensure the indexes are rebuilt on publish without switching over to master slave on solr ?

Comment: You would need to look into "publish end REMOTE". But why waste CPU if you can use Solr replication?

Comment: Do you have an option to run full republish? I think it might update Solr cores on CD.

Comment: @marek , thanks for you reply Long term plan is to use solr replication , is theer a short term fix for this problem ? ,

Comment: There is no easier fix then setting replication I'm afraid

Comment: Can you post your configuration file where OnPublishEndAsync is defined. It should index after publish but there might be something else wrong in configuration. You shouldnt need replication for indexing.